# Remove time when exported to pdf

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2017-express

My datagridview doesn't have the time in datePurchased column. But when I exported it to PDF, it already includes the time. I need only the date not the time. Below is the sample code

```
 //For exporting to pdf

      Private Sub ExportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As  EventArgs) Handles ExportButton.Click
  connection.Close()
  connection.Open()

  Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(ReportDataGridView.ColumnCount)
  pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 1
  pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
  pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element. ALIGN_CENTER

  Dim ptable As New  Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)

    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn in ReportDataGridView.Columns
  Dim cell as new PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(column.HeaderText, ptable)))
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
  cell.FixedHeight = 30
  pdfTable.AddCell(cell)

  Next

    For Each row as DataGridViewRow In ReportDataGridView.Rows
  For each cell as DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
  pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString)
  Next
  Next

 Dim folderpath As String = "C:\PDFs\"
 If Not Directory.Exists(folderpath) Then
      Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath)
 End If

  Using sfd as New 
SaveFileDialog()
 sfd.ShowDialog()
 sfd.OverWritePrompt = True
 sfd.Title =" Save As"
 sfd.AddExtension = True
 sfd.DefaultExt = ".pdf"

  Using stream As New FileStream(sfd.FileName & ".pdf", 
   FileMode.Create)
  Dim pdfdoc As New 
  Document (PageSize.LETTER, 36.0F, 36.0F,36.0F,36.0F)
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc.stream)
  pdfdoc.Open()
  pdfdoc.Add(pdfTable)
  pdfdoc.Close()
  stream.Close()
  If File.Exists("path") Then
       File.AppendAllText("path", "contents")
   End If
  pdfdoc.Close()
  stream.Close()
  End Using

  End Using
  End Sub
```

If you would ask me what's the data type of DatePurchased, it is date. I used date not datetime. Please help!

Comment: A date and a time are related to the same concept - expressing a moment in the future/in history - the underlying type is DateTime and always has a date and a time. In your grid you only see the date part of the datetime, because that is all your grid textbox is formatting to show (it is showing MM/dd/yyyy or whatever) though the time component of the datetime still exists. You must apply the same formatting when you emit the value

Answer (score 0):

You would have to detect dates and explicitly format without time, e.g.

```vb
For each cell as DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
    Dim cellValue = cell.Value

    pdfTable.AddCell(If(TypeOf cellValue Is Date,
                        CDate(cellValue).ToShortDateString(),
                        cellValue.ToString()))
Next
```